# How do I remove custom blocks from category pages in Magento

Tags: magento

I have Magento's html5 mobile theme installed as an additional theme just for mobiles. My main/default theme is great for responsive designs but not for mobile hence the addition of the html5 theme for mobiles. I need to know how to remove my static blocks from the  top of my category pages. Any help greatly appreciated. I want the static blocks to remain in place on the site, but not on the mobile version - otherwise I'd simply remove them hence the question. I was wondering if I could use a layout.xml file to achieve this. Please be specific if you can help.

Comment: How you have added static block to category pages, by catalog.xml or by updating .phtml file? If possible share your code.

Comment: I used Magento's category (out of the box) management functionality. I haven't manually edited any files.

Comment: As per my understanding, while create category you have selected Display Mode : Static blocks and products & CMS Block : Selected you Desire cms block Under Display Settings. Please let me know, am I right?

Comment: That is correct Rajiv...

Comment: Yes, I have posted answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these steps:

Copy: `app\design\frontend\SITE-PACKAGE\SITE-YOUR_CUSTOM_TEMPLATE\template\catalog\category\view.phtml`

Paste: `app\design\frontend\MOBILE-PACKAGE\MOBILE-YOUR_CUSTOM_TEMPLATE\template\catalog\category\view.phtml`

Now, open mobile version `view.phtml`:

Remove below code:

```
<?php if($this->isContentMode()): ?>
    <?php echo $this->getCmsBlockHtml() ?>

<?php elseif($this->isMixedMode()): ?>
    <?php echo $this->getCmsBlockHtml() ?>
    <?php echo $this->getProductListHtml() ?>

<?php else: ?>
    <?php echo $this->getProductListHtml() ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Add:

```
<?php echo $this->getProductListHtml() ?>
```

Hope it will help you!

Comment: Perfect. That worked a treat. My only slight issue now is that I have two pages that just contain a CMS block, I might have to somehow remove them from the nav bar. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

```
Using template path hints you can easily find your template path files.
Login to admin pannel and under
- System -> Configuration
- Change the “Configuration Scope” to “Default Store View” (or whichever store view you want to see template paths on)
- Under Advanced in the left menu click Developer
- Click “Debug” to expand that section
- Change “Template Path Hints”  to "Yes"
- Click Save Configuration
Now to refresh the front-end and see all the locations of the template files so you can easily modify the correct ones. 
Hope it will helps you.
```